# How to choose gtk version for Eclipse RCP application in linux?

Tags: linux, eclipse, gtk, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP application which I want to run in Linux environment that has multiple gtks installed.

Is there a way to choose the gtk version against which I can run the application?

Linux flavour: openSUSE
Window Manager: iceWM
gtk versions installed: 1.2.10 & 2.2.1